# Pass JSON Object to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, pug

I am trying to pass json object to angular directive but can't find any solution yet.

here is the code.

**Directive**

```
 function agEcalendar() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/components/ecalendar/ecalendar.html',
      scope: {
          event: '@event'
      },
      controller: EcalendarController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
  }
```

and here i am calling the directive in jade

```
ag-ecalendar(event='{{vm.calendar.event}}')
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this directive? Should the `controller` be in quotes? `controller: "EcalendarController"`

Answer (score 4):

Do pass object using `<`(new one way binding options) which will give you ability to pass object to directive isolated scope.

```
scope: {
    event: '<event'
},
```

**HTML**

```
ag-ecalendar(event='vm.calendar.event')
```

In current case it is getting passed with `@` is nothing but converting object value to `string`.

> **Note** The suggested way would work for Angular 1.5+ version, otherwise you need to make it as `event: '=event'`(eventually that will enable two way binding)

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi is it really angular version? did you try what I told you?

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi you must have looking somewhere else, angular has `1.5.5` as latest version which they had released recently

Comment: ohh my bad. its v1.5.2

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi lets try what I've suggest, & let me know if it works or not

Comment: when i try '<' or '=', it gives me this error 
"Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{vm.calendar.event}}] starting at [{vm.calendar.event}}]."

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi look at the updated answer.. I forget to mention the html code,

Comment: now when i try to retrieve the value of event, it says 
event: undefined

Comment: Could you add plunkr with issue, I'll look at it

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi could you add plunkr please, with reproducable problem?